# Adding fragment into framelayout cause support-actionbar hiding

Tags: android, android-support-library

When I add a fragment in the FrameLayout, the new fragment hide the compat-v7 supportActionBar (the fragment contains text in yellow).

[image]

Here is my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include layout="@layout/app_bar_main" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here is how I load the fragment into the framelayout:

```
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, TimerFragment.newInstance(talkList[0]))
            .commitNow()
```

..and here is the TimerFragment xml content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ui.main.TimerFragment">

...

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**EDIT**

I add app_bar_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".TalksActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**EDIT 2**

With the help of Mohsen, here is my main_activity.xml now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include layout="@layout/app_bar_main" />

<FrameLayout
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**------- SOLUTION--------**

Thanks to Mohsen here is what I did. The solution is to have `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` only in the `FrameLayout` and nowhere else.
Moreover, the FrameLayout must be inside the `CoordinatorLayout`.

Here is my new activity_main.xml (app_bar_main.xml removed):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">


<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".TalksActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Try after giving Bg Color to your fragments layout!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Add:**

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

To the `FrameLayout` and remove it from `DrawerLayout`.

**Explanation:** You should be using this line to tell that `Fragment` goes under the `AppBarLayout` as the content but in your case, `DrawerLayout` is the content now, so removing that line from `DrawerLayout` and adding it to the `FrameLayout` will solve the issue.

---

**Update:** Here is the working layout: (Use `FrameLayout` inside the `CoordinatorLayout`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: I did what you say, but unfortunately this did not fix the problem.

Comment: In which file? I checked I have only one `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` in my app. Look at **EDIT 2** to see my activity_main.xml

Comment: Do you want to see the xml of my fragment?

Comment: I checked with a full text research on `layout_behavior` in the project, I have only one result which is in the `FrameLayout`.
Have look at EDIT3 for the fragment content.

Comment: The `FrameLayout` was outside of `CoordinatorLayout` + few changes which you can see in my updated answer. It should work now

Comment: OK! I understand what you mean. I added my `FrameLayout` into the `CoordinatorLayout`. But now my `FrameLayout` is inside the app_bar_main.xml file. Now I have to reorganize my files. Thank @Mohsen it's working now.

Comment: Well yeah, I made it a bit clear to understand by merging them in one layout. You can do your changes as you wish. Glad to help

Comment: Actually I don't need the app_bar_main.xml anymore. Thanks again!